# Trouble with executing Angular directive method on parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive inside a directive, and need to call a parent method using the child directive. I'm having a bit of trouble passing the data around, and thought y'all might have an idea.

Here's the setup:

My parent directive is called `screener-item`. My child directive is called `option-item`. Inside of every `screener-item`, there might be n `option-item`s, so they're dynamically added. (Essentially, think of this as dynamically building a dropdown: the user gives it a title, then a set of options available)

Here's how this is set up:

`screener-item.directive.js`

```
angular.module('recruitingApp')                                                                                              
  .directive('screenerItem', function(Study, $compile) {                                                                
    return {                                                                                                            
      templateUrl: 'app/new-study/screener-item/screener-item.html',                                                    
      scope: {                                                                                                          
        study: '='                                                                                                      
      },                                                                                                                
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {                                                                                
        var options = [];  

        scope.addOptionItem = function(item) {                                                                          
          options.push(item);                                                                                                                                                               
        }      

        scope.saveScreenerItem = function() {                                                                           
          if (scope.item._id) {                                                                                         
            var isEdit = true;                                                                                          
          }                                                                                                             
          Study.addScreenerQuestion({id:scope.study._id},{                                                              
            _id: scope.item._id,                                                                                        
            text: scope.item.text,                                                                                      
            type: scope.item.type                                                                                       
          }, function(item){                                                                                            
            scope.mode = 'show';                                                                                        
            scope.item._id = item._id;                                                                                  
            if (!isEdit) {                                                                                              
              el.parent().append($compile('<screener-item study="newStudy.study"></screener-item')(scope.$parent));     
            }                                                                                                           
          });                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                               
      }                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                   
  });
```

`screener-item.html`

```
<div class="screener-item row" ng-hide="mode == 'show'">                                                                   
    <div class="col-md-8">                                                                                                   
    <input type="text" placeholder="Field (e.g., name, email)" ng-model="item.text">                                    
    </div>                                                                                                                
    <div class="col-md-3">                                                                                                
      <select ng-model="item.type">                                                                                       
        <option value="text">Text</option>                                                                                
        <option value="single_choice">Single Select</option>                                                              
        <option value="multi_choice">Multi Select</option>                                                                
      </select>                                                                                                           
      <div ng-show="item.type == 'single_choice' || fieldType == 'multi_choice'">                                         
        <h6>Possible answers:</h6>                                                                                        
        <option-item item-options="options" add-option-item="addOptionItem(value)"><option-item>                          
      </div>                                                                                                              
    </div>                                                                                                                
    <div class="col-md-1">                                                                                                
      <button ng-click="saveScreenerItem()">Save</button>                                                                 
    </div>                                                                                                                
  </div>                                                                                                                  
  <div class="screener-item-show row" ng-model="item" ng-show="mode == 'show'">                                           
    <div class="col-md-8">{{item.text}}</div>                                                                             
    <div class="col-md-3">({{item.type}})</div>                                                                           
    <div class="col-md-1">                                                                                                
      <a ng-click="mode = 'add'">edit</a>                                                                                 
    </div>                                                                                                                
  </div>
```

You'll notice `option-item` which is included there in them middle. That's the initial option offered to the user. This may be repeated, as the user needs it to be.

`option.item.directive.js`

```
angular.module('recruitingApp')                                                                                            
  .directive('optionItem', function($compile) {                                                                            
    return {                                                                                                               
      templateUrl: 'app/new-study/screener-item/option-item.html',                                                         
      scope: {                                                                                                             
        addOptionItem: '&'                                                                                                 
      },                                                                                                                   
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {                                                                                   
        scope.mode = 'add';                                                                                                
        scope.addItem = function(value) {                                                                                  
          console.log("Value is ", value);                                                                                 
          scope.addOptionItem({item:value});                                                                               
          scope.mode = 'show';                                                                                             
          var newOptionItem = $compile('<option-item add-option-item="addOptionItem"></option-item')(scope);               
          el.parent().append(newOptionItem);                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                  
      }                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                      
  });
```

`option-item.html`

```
 <div ng-show="mode == 'add'">                                                                                           
   <input type="text" ng-model="value">                                                                                  
     <button ng-click="addItem(value)">Save</button>                                                                       
 </div>
```

Here's what I want to happen: When the user enters a value in the `option-item` textbox and saves it, I want to call `addItem()`, a method on the `option-item` directive. That method, then, would call the parent method - `addOptionItem()`, passing along the value, which gets pushed into an array that's kept on the parent (this array keeps track of all the options added).

I can get it to execute the parent method, but for the life of me, I can't get it to pass the values - it comes up as `undefined` each time.

I'm trying to call the `option-item` method instead of going straight to the parent, so that I can do validation if needed, and so I can dynamically add another `option-item` underneath the current one, once an item is added.

I hope this makes sense, please let me know if this is horribly unclear.

Thanks a ton!

EDIT: Here's a jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/y4uzbapz/1/

Note that when you add options, the logged out array of options on the parent is undefined.

Comment: Can you please create JSFiddle with your code?

Comment: Yeah, give me a bit to reconstruct it as accurately as possible.

Comment: @TomePejoski fiddle created here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4uzbapz/1/

Comment: @JustinDavis you can check this article to get an idea how should directives communicate...

Answer (score 0):

Got this working. All the tutorials have this working by calling the parent method on `ng-click`, essentially bypassing the child controller. But, if you need to do validation before passing the value up to the parent, you need to call a method on the child directive, then invoke the parent directive's method within that call.

Turns out, you can access it just the same way that you can as if you were putting the expression inside of `ng-click`.

Here's a fiddle showing this working: http://jsfiddle.net/y4uzbapz/3/

Notice that the `ng-click` handler is actually on the child directive, which calls the parent directive's method. This lets me do some pre/post processing on that data, which I couldn't do if I'd invoked the parent directive directly from `ng-click`.

Anyway, case closed :)